# Getting UIButton width before viewDidAppear, with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I have a UIButton (created in interface builder), that I'm turning into a circle by setting `button.layer.borderRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2.0;` (programatically, in viewDidAppear:). However, the viewController it belongs to is presented modally with an animation. Since `viewDidAppear` isn't called until after the transition animation has finished, the button is square until then, which makes the sudden change quite jarring.

I can't set the radius in `viewDidLoad`, since the button properties are incorrect then (the width is too large), which I think is because autolayout constraints haven't been properly resolved yet. I tried to rectify this by calling `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` in `viewDidLoad`, and then setting the cornerRadius, but the button width was still wrong. What I don't understand is, during the animation, everything otherwise renders correctly, suggesting that the autolayout constraints /have/ been resolved, or that iOS does something else in the name of quick animations (like storing a snapshot preview to use for the animation).

Any suggestions?

The result of trying to set the corner radius in viewDidLoad:

[image: The result of trying to set the corner radius in viewDidLoad]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the width in the function 
`- viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) here.

Answer (score 3):

Override the `UIButton` and make its `layoutSubviews` method like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width/2.f;
}
```

Then whenever the button's size changes it will adjusts its value.
Also add it in `buttonWithType:` and `initWithFrame:` as I'm not sure if the `layoutSubviews` is called after init.

Comment: I've accepted the top answer because it more directly answers the question I asked, but for my situation, this is the better solution I think. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This only works if the button is square. After calling `sizeToFit()` to get it to have a meaningful size, it will typically be rectangular...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't get you well. As your screenshot explains that your image isn't being circular.For that you can try:(1) layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width/2; or layer.CornerRadius = 50(if width is 100)

```
 layer.masksToBounds = YES;

 layer.borderWidth = 1.5; or whatever you want

 layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

If still you get problem, then share your constraints that you added on button and also the code where you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Your controls get the constraints and frame set after viewDidLoad amd after viewDidLoad you can get your requirements in viewwilllayoutsubviews or in viewdidlayoutsubviews before viewDidAppear

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```